# How to change the behavior of clicking an option item of v-autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

**Scenario**

When clicking an option item, natively, the v-autocomplete (with multiple prop) active its respective checkbox and keeps with the menu open, allowing you to continue selecting other items until you click out of the menu

[image: v-autocomplete multiple]

**Objective**

What I would like is to change this behavior, when I clicked only in the checkbox, the native behavior is maintained, but when clicked specifically on the line, the menu is closed and trigger a function using the value of the selected item.

I imagine that it is necessary to use the slots but I really don't know how to use it or if this is the best way to obtain this new behavior.

[image: v-autocomplete multiple]

**Note**

The vertical line is for concept demonstration purposes only, it is not necessary to include this line in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you can do it using slots. The idea is to override items display to remove the clickable `v-list-item` underneath. The drawback is that you have to re-implement values selection.

You'll need a checkbox and two methods: `isSelected` and `toggleItem`.

Template section:

```html
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="values"
    :items="items"
    outlined
    dense
    chips
    small-chips
    label="Outlined"
    multiple
>
    <template #item="{ item }">
        <v-list-item class="d-flex">
            <div>
                <v-simple-checkbox color="primary" :value="isSelected(item)" @click="toggleItem(item)" />
            </div>
            <div class="ml-2">{{ item }}</div>
        </v-list-item>
    </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Script section:

```js
  data: () => ({
    items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
    values: ['foo', 'bar'],
  }),
  methods: {
    isSelected(item) {
      return this.values.includes(item);
    },
    toggleItem(item) {
      if (this.values.includes(item)) {
        this.values = this.values.filter(v => v !== item);
      } else {
        this.values.push(item);
      }
    }
  }
```

Please take a look at this [working example](https://codepen.io/chamboug/pen/eYgvOWo?editors=1011).

Comment: Thank you!!! You saved several hours of research and attempts. The part of selecting only the item and close the menu was easy now. The part of separating the checkbox the way you did, it was really good. Thanks. https://codepen.io/magnoalberto/pen/vYgxYNd?editors=1011